# Upload Image to resource with REST Webservice

Tags: php, rest, web-services, exact-synergy-enterprise

I'm trying to upload a personal photo of and employee to Exact Synergy Enterprise with the Exact Synergy REST webservice. 
To update other information like: FirstName, LastName etc. I use Guzzle HTTP with this code:

```
$type = "POST";
$entity = "Resource"
$json = array(
"FirstName" = "John",
"LastName=" = "Doe"
);
$res = $client->request($type,config('exact.webservice_url').$entity, [
                'auth' => [
                    config('exact.webservice_user'), config('exact.webservice_password'), config('exact.webservice_digest')
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-type' => 'application/json',
                    'X-HTTP-Method' => 'MERGE',
                ],
                'json' => $json,
                ['timeout' => 10]
            ]);
```

Is it possible to upload a image to the same webservice? 
There is some information about the webservice at: http://www.exactsoftware.com/docs/DocView.aspx?DocumentID=%7bd2dcb5be-d6cc-4e95-9bb4-b3333bc73dde%7d&NoHeader=1&NoSubject=1

Comment: Are you asking someone else to read the documentation for you?

Comment: I'm sorry, this sounds like a ridiculous answer.. Maybe someone said: I should change tihs in your code and it works.. I'm sorry for asking ;)